# Using tootips with lists [HTML, CSS]

Tags: html, css, tooltip, html-lists

Looked at W3School's tooltips guide and basically retyped it, but the example doesn't use a list, and I am using a list for a practice website I'm doing. As a result, it's formatted weirdly.

I tried messing around with it, removing the li tag and it worked but it isn't what I'm looking for.

```
h1 {
    color: #D3D3D3;
}

.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .toolptiptext::after; {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    }
```

I expect it to be a list that when you hover over it'll show the tooltip, formatted the same as a regular HTML list. That's really it.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the HTML of your page?

Comment: Oh, sorry! I've already got it to work using Jens Ingel's suggestion, but if you want I can show you it.

Comment: No need to since the accepted answer included sample HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.tooltiplink::after {
  visibility: hidden;
  content: attr(name);
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -1rem;
  padding: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
.tooltiplink:hover::after {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="tooltiplink" name="This is a tooltip">Option 1
  </li>
  <li class="tooltiplink" name="This is a tooltip for the 2th option">Option 2
  </li>
  <li class="tooltiplink" name="This is a tooltip for the 3th option">Option 3
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oops added dubble padding over their. Just take the last one.

Answer (score 1):

I think I made it work like you want. Try adding this to your code

```
li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

li:before {
  content: '\ffed';
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

Like this

```css
  .tooltip {
    position: relative;
  }

  li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

  li:before {
  content: '\ffed';
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

  .tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -5px;
    left: 110%;
  }

  .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 100%;
    margin-top: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
  }
  .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
  }
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li class="tooltip">
        Hover over me
      <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
      </li>
      <li class="tooltip">
And again
<span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</li>
    </ul>
```